# Homotopy of space of immersions, Smale-Hirsch theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory, differential-topology, isometric-immersion

If $M$ and $N$  are  manifolds with $\dim M< \dim N$, we denote by $Imm\left(M,N\right)$ the space of immersions of $M$ in $N$.

Let $M$ and $M'$ be a simply connected manifolds of dimensions $m>0$. It is true that if $M$ is homotopic to $M'$, then for $k\geq m$, the spaces $Imm\left(M,\mathbb{R}^{m+k}\right)$ and $Imm\left(M',\mathbb{R}^{m+k}\right)$ are homotopic? i.e

if  $k\geq m$, then $M\simeq M'\Rightarrow Imm\left(M,\mathbb{R}^{m+k}\right)\simeq Imm\left(M',\mathbb{R}^{m+k}\right)$?

Thanks

Abdoul

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. For example, if $M$ is a Moebius band then, at least for even $k$, $Imm(M,\mathbb R^{2+k})$ is not homotopy equivalent to $Imm(S^1\times \mathbb R,\mathbb R^{2+k})$.

The latter is equivalent to the space of all maps from $S^1$ to $O(2+k)/O(k)$. Its first non-trivial homotopy group is $\pi_{k-1}=\pi_k(O(2+k)/O(k))=\mathbb Z$.

The former is equivalent to the space of sections of a nontrivial bundle with base $S^1$ and fiber $O(2+k)/O(k)$, in which the action of the fundamental group of the base on $\pi_k(O(2+k)/O(k))$ is nontrivial. Its first non-trivial homotopy group is $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this example. It is possible to have an example for simply connected manifolds? Because in this case the action of the base on the fiber is always trivial. Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you take $M$ to be a rank two vector bundle over $S^2$ with odd Euler class then $Imm(M,\mathbb R^{4+k})$ is inequivalent to $Imm(S^2\times \mathbb R^2,\mathbb R^{4+k})$ for large $k$.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to prove that. But,  the mean of "M to be a rank two vector bundle over $S^2$" is not very clear for me. Could  you explain it to me please? Thank you again. Abdoul

Comment: rank means dimension of the fibers

Comment: Sorry, I need some explanation about $M$( I refer to $M$ of the example), please.  I understand that $M$ is the total space of vector bundle of rank two. My problem is that: it's possible to have a four manifold with odd Euler class? Thanks

Comment: The Euler class that I mean is an element of $H^2(S^2)$, the Euler class of a rank two oriented vector bundle on $S^2$. Such a bundle remains non-trivial when added to the tangent bundle of $S^2$ if and only its Euler class maps to the nontrivial element of $H^2(S^2;\mathbb Z/2)$.

Comment: My guess above is simply wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Note that when $M$ and $M′$ are simply connected, I have a positive answer in the rational case. I.e

If $k\geq m$ is an odd integer, then $M\simeq M'\Rightarrow Imm\left(M,\mathbb{R}^{m+k}\right)\simeq_{\mathbb{Q}}Imm\left(M',\mathbb{R}^{m+k}\right).$

Here $"\simeq_{\mathbb{Q}}"$ denotes the rational homotopy equivalence.